# Apache Drill http "Error parsing JSON - Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value"

Tags: apache-drill

I'm using Apache Drill with http storage.

For one particular entry, it cannot parse the JSON that is coming back.

```
> DATA_READ_ERROR: Error parsing JSON- Unexpected character('<' (code
> 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number (or
> 'NAN`/'INF'/'+INF'), Array, Object or token 'null', 'true', or
> 'false') at  [Source: (okio.RealBufferedSource$inputStream$1); line:
> 1, column: 2]
```

I've double checked the url it is hitting and it is returning back application/json as the content type, so I have no idea why it's not parsing this particular API connection.

This is also the only API connection that doesn't work. The others I have set up work properly.

The API setting

```
> "prometheus": {   "url": "http://.../api/v1/query",   "requireTail":
> true,   "method": "GET",   "dataPath": "data",   "authType": "none",  
> "inputType": "json",   "xmlDataLevel": 1,   "verifySSLCert": true, }
```

Comment: Peter, could you share a sample of the data that is being returned?  This looks like either some malformed JSON or some other schema-related issue.

Comment: Figured it out. It was my internal proxy server returning back an html response that the URL I was pointing to needed to be confirmed instead of a JSON Reply.

Unfortunately, these things are hard to figure out in drill, as I can't see the actual response it's trying to parse out. I needed to go to the source and work it out from there.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Would you mind creating an issue (https://github.com/apache/drill/issues) and we can add some functionality to help debug these kinds of things?